# Reverse a linked list in Scheme

Tags: linked-list, scheme, lisp, reverse

I am trying to reverse a linked list in Scheme; and I have no idea why this isn't working. I am using Chez Scheme by the way. It is giving me this error: Exception: incorrect number of arguments to #procedure reverse-ll at reverse-linked-list.scm:59. Does anyone have an idea as to what is happening? Thanks!

```
(define pi '(3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5))

(define reverse-ll
  (lambda (orig rev)
                (if (null? (cdr orig)) rev
                           (reverse-ll (cons (car orig) rev)))))

(define reverse-pi (reverse-ll pi '()))
(display reverse-pi)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that a call to `reverse-ll` does not have enough arguments, and there are only two such calls. The call `(reverse-ll pi '())` is fine, since `reverse-ll` takes two list arguments. The other call is the problem:

```
(reverse-ll (cons (car orig) rev))
```

Here `reverse-ll` is given only one argument: `(cons (car orig) rev)`. This expression is adding the first element of the input list to the accumulator. But the code is missing the reduced input list for the recursive step. Instead:

```
(reverse-ll (cdr orig) (cons (car orig) rev))
```

There is another problem. As written, the code does not include the last element of the input list in the reversed output. This is because of the base case:

```
(if (null? (cdr orig)) rev ;; )
```

In this code the base case is reached when `(cdr orig)` is `'()`, and that happens when the input list has been reduced to a length of one element. The last element is then not processed by the `reverse-ll` procedure. Instead you want an empty list in the input to trigger the return of the accumulator:

```
(define reverse-ll
  (lambda (orig rev)
                (if (null? orig) rev
                           (reverse-ll (cdr orig) (cons (car orig) rev)))))
```

Here is the result, showing both input and output:

```
> (load "scratch.ss")
(3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5)
(5 3 5 6 2 9 5 1 4 1 3)
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you!